# Transposing SQL query to eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I've been stuck on transposing this sql query to eloquent. I've tried quite a fair bit but the eloquent results were not returning in the format i want, namely:

```
Vuln A
 - Host 1
 - Host 2

Vul B
 - Host 3

Vul C
 - Host 1
 - Host 2
 - Host 5
```

These are my models.

### Models (Many to Many)

```
Host
- id
- apptype
- country
- ...

Vuln
- id
- severity
- ...

Host_Vuln
- id
- Host_id
- Vul_id
- Mesg
- ...
```

### Queries

I have the following SQL extraction which in mysql

```
SELECT * from Vuln 
INNER JOIN Host_Vuln on Host_Vuln.Vuln_id = Vuln.id
INNER JOIN Host on Host_Vuln.Host_id = Host.id
WHERE (Host.country = 1) AND (Host.apptype like 'Mob%')
ORDER BY Vuln.severity DESC
```

But I'm stuck on Eloquent... This is what I have

```
  $vulnResult = DB::table('vulns')
    ->join('host_vuln', 'vulns.id', '=', 'host_vuln.finding_id')
    ->join('hosts', 'host_vuln.host_id', '=', 'hosts.id')
    ->where('hosts.country', 1)
    ->where('hosts.apptype', 'like', 'Web%')
    ->orderBy('vulns.score', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

where the results were returned in an collection without nesting Hosts under a Vuln. The resulting collection is a plain array where each Host is mapped to a Vuln, even when a Vuln has many Hosts. This is inefficent duplication which i want to eliminate.

The end result i want is Each Vuln can have many Hosts. If there is no Hosts, then do not display the Vuln.

Comment: I think there is typo issue. **vuln_host** should be **host_vulns** try this 
` $vulnss = DB::table('vulns')
    ->join('host_vulns', 'vulns.id', '=', 'host_vulns.finding_id')
    ->join('hosts', 'vuln_host.host_id', '=', 'hosts.id')
    ->where('hosts.country', 1)
    ->where('hosts.apptype', 'like', 'Mob%')
    ->orderBy('vulns.severity', 'DESC')
    ->get();`

Comment: Hey thanks! I've tested it out but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I was such a dumbarse. The following was perfect (though I still didn't get *it; why it worked*)

```
    $filter = function ($w) { 
        $w->where('country', 1)
          ->where('apptype', 'like', 'Mob%'); 
    };

    $findings1 = Vuln::with(['hosts' => $filter])
                    ->whereHas('hosts', $filter)
                    ->get();
```